# How to fix /wp/ redirect to /blog/ permalink

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, permalinks

I'm a new user and frankly, I haven't got a clue what I'm doing at this point. I'm figuring things out slowly but surely and this site has so far been a gold mine for me... So, let's see if we can make this work.

So, my website has a WordPress installation within the root directory to allow me to have a blog; WordPress is installed solely for the blog and this is in the `public_html/wp` folder. Everything within the `wp` folder is WordPress.

Now, when I write a post, the permalink is `my-website.co.uk/wp/post-title`.
The `.htaccess` file rewrites this permalink to `my-website.co.uk/blog/post-title`.

This is great, looks much better but the problem is, when WordPress auto-shares the posts, the `/wp/post-title` permalink redirects to homepage and not to the relevant blog post. This means, whenever someone clicks on the shared link, they're taken to my homepage (sorry if I sound like I'm dumbing it down).

Now, in the `public_html` folder, I have one `.htaccess` file which is as follows

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/do-not-touch.php do-not-touch.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.htm -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.htm [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ $0/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9-]+)/?$ blog.php?page=$1
RewriteRule ^blog/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ blog.php?slug=$1

RedirectMatch 301 ^/tenants.htm /information-for-tenants.htm
```

Then, in the WP folder, we have another `.htaccess` file:

```
#+PHPVersion
#="php70"
AddHandler x-httpd-php70 .php
#-PHPVersion

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

---

My theory (remember, I have no idea what I'm doing) is that the second `.htaccess` file redirects the `/wp/` permalinks up to the `public_html` file index (shown by the RewriteBase `/wp/ RewriteRule ^index\.php$` --- Not sure what the `\.php$` does) whilst the first `.htaccess` file rewrites the `/wp/post-title` to `/blog/post-title` (shown by `RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9-]+)/?$ blog.php?page=$1` and `RewriteRule ^blog/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ blog.php?slug=$1`).

---

**Finally**, in my WordPress admin permalink settings, the selected permalink is shown as `my-website.co.uk/wp/sample-post/`.
All permalinks are `my-website.co.uk/wp/[customisable]` -- In other words, it doesn't allow me to alter the `/wp/` section of the permalink.

I could really use some help. I need to redirect `wp/post-title` (whatever the title may be) to `blog/post-title` instead of `/index`.

As a result of the redirect, search engines fail to crawl my blog posts (I think?).

This is my website blog: https://www.harryalbertgroup.co.uk/blog

And this is the WP permalink: https://www.harryalbertgroup.co.uk/wp

Thanks in advance.

(Note: This website was built for me. I've been slowly fixing all of the issues I've faced so far. We're slowly getting there, it's really just the sharing features that I need to fix now, from what I can see)

Comment: Do you have access to **/etc/apache2/sites-available** ? If yes you can set the Virtual Host to target the wp folder directly inside the public_html.  If you have access please add the virtual host content currently being used.  If you never edited the virtual hosts it should be the 000-default one. Or else you can rename the **wp** folder to **blog** and set the Site address in general settings to yourdomain.co.uk/blog

Comment: @OmarTanti - I do not have access to that. Is that on the servers?
If so, I have no access to servers.

Comment: Can't you contact your hosting prividers about this issue? Apart from the wp folder, do you have any other folders in public_html?